# IIS8 rewrite to force https except for a certain path

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-8

My site is asp.net.
I have a wordpress blog in the blog folder and everything works great.

My main web.config has a working rule that forces https on everything.

I have successfully added a rule in the web.config in the blog folder not to redirect to https.
My problem is that I want to exclude the wp-content/uploads/* folder from that rule.
i.e. I want the images in the  upload folder to be allowed to load on https too.
(My reason is that I refer to them in my main site and the way it is, I get security messages that I have insecure content on my https pages)

My code is:

```
 <rule name="Remove https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
       <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^wp-content/uploads/.*" negate="true" />
       <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/blog/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code in problem dear plz try below code can this help you.

Something Wrong in your pattern of "^wp-content/uploads/.*" you try below code can this help you.

```
     <rule name="Remove https" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
       <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*)" negate="true" />
       <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/blog/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: I don't want to negate all those folders.
I only want to negate the wp-content/uploads folder

Comment: Neither one of us noticed the mistake.
It should have been action type=none